# Copy Data from other Sheet and insert it with an emty cell (column) every other cell (with image cells)

Tags: google-sheets, insert, cell, google-sheets-formula

I want to copy data from another Sheet that doesn't matter if it's with {MySheet!A1:A4} or with IMPORTRANGE or whatever. And insert the Data into another Sheet transposed but inserting an empty column or cell every other row (so basically skip would work). To make it a bit more difficult I'm having pictures in some of the rows so sometimes there is no text but only inserted pictures.

So if my original table would be

```
A1 (Content="TextfromCellA1"), 
A2 (Content=ImageInCell1), 
A3 (Content="TextfromCellA3"), 
A4 (Content=ImageInCell2)
```

I want to print the cells like this

```
A1 (Content="TextfromCellA1"),
B1 (Content=empty),
C1 (Content=ImageInCell1),
D1 (Content=empty),
E1 (Content="TextfromCellA3"),
F1 (Content=empty),
G1 (Content=ImageInCell2),
```

I for sure can start with:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MySheet!A1:A4)
```

I tried Querys and everything but couldn't get it to work.
Here's one thing I tried as well, but it will give me an error message as i can't concat the image that is in the cells :/

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A20),5)=0,A1:A20&REPT(" ",3),A1:A20)),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simple, may be like this:

```
={A1,"",A2,"",A3,"",A4}
```

Using Query and transpose:

```
=query({Transpose(A1:A4),"","",""}, "Select Col1, Col5, Col2, Col6, Col3, Col7, Col4")
```